How can I fix custom dimensions not updating in Google Tag Manager for a Single Page Application (SPA)?
I'm having trouble getting custom dimensions to update correctly in Google Tag Manager (GTM) for my Single Page Application (SPA), and I'd appreciate any advice on how to resolve this.
My Setup:

Next.js 14 with React

Google Tag Manager

GA4 (Google Analytics 4)


The Problem:
In GTM debug mode, when I change routes in my SPA, the page view is recorded as expected. However, the custom dimension data (specifically publication_date) is either missing or not updated correctly when navigating between pages.
What I’ve Tried:
To demonstrate the issue, I’m using the publication_date event property. Its value is set to new Date().getTime()

First Page Load:
The custom dimension value for publication_date is correctly recorded in the page view:
publication_date in gtm hit

After Route Change:
Upon navigating to another page, the page view still shows the same publication_date, even though the value in the dataLayer has changed:
publication_date in dataLayer


Code Snippet:
In the main layout of my Next.js app, I’ve added GTM like this:
<GoogleTagManager gtmId="*****" />

And in a client component, I push events to the dataLayer using the following code:
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: "MyCustomEvent",
  publication_date: new Date().getTime()
});

My Setup in GTM:
I have a tag connected to GA4, which is triggered by the custom event "MyCustomEvent". Here’s a screenshot of the GTM setup:
GTM setup
Question:
How can I ensure that the custom dimension values (like publication_date) update correctly in GTM(page view) when navigating between routes in a SPA? Any guidance on what might be going wrong or suggestions for improvement would be highly appreciated!

Values set under the config tag won't re-evaluated. Did you try removing it from the config tag & sending it only as an event param?

Yes, I tried removing the values from the config tag and sending them as event parameters, but the data was still not presented correctly.
After some investigation, I found this article:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/#developers-help
and followed Method 3 to resolve the issue.
Thanks for your suggestion! If anyone else encounters problems with missing or outdated data in SPAs, especially with Next.js, I highly recommend checking this method - it worked for me.
